# Why are some variables inside single quote not escaped in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!bin/bash

outfile="members.sql"
IFS=','

while read lname fname address city state zip; do
    cat >> $outfile << EOF
    INSERT INTO members (lname,fname,address,city,state,zip) VALUES
    ('$lname', '$fname', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip');
EOF
done < ${1}
```

The input file is a .csv file with data like `Blum,Richard,123 Main St.,Chicago,IL,60601`.

Why does this code work? As I know, everything inside a single quote are taken literally right? Why are these variables be substituted?

My guess is that it's a two-step process, first it WAS taken literally when the STDIN redirection happened, and then it IS SUBSTITUTED when appended into the outfile, am I close? How does this actually work?

Comment: _Within a heredoc_ single quotes have no special meaning.

Comment: (This is asking for SQL injection.)

Comment: What matters with a heredoc is whether the sigil `<< 'EOF'` is quoted -- that will prevent variable expansion within the heredoc.

Comment: @Biffen Haha, this would not appear in production, it's just an example code in a book. Thank you for the kind reminder haha.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, I should have read the manual of here documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a here document `'` means literally `'`. It has no special meaning.

```
$ cat <<EOF
> '
> EOF
'
```

> is that it's a two-step process

I would say it's one step. You take all lines between here doc delimiter `<<EOF` and `EOF` and then do variable expansion on `$strings` and then output. You can read about it in documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents :

> [...] all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence \newline is ignored, and ‘\’ must be used to quote the characters ‘\’, ‘$’, and ‘`’.